# Autocomplete textbox not progressing to the next record

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

I use the code below to get the information in the textbox, but when it runs it only shows the first record of the database.  How can I get the next record?

VBScript...

```vbs
Dim Leads
Dim Leads_cmd
Dim Leads_numRows
Set Leads_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
Leads_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_PSCRM_STRING
Leads_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT lead_desc from dba.lead" 
Leads_cmd.Prepared = true
Set Leads = Leads_cmd.Execute
Leads_numRows = 0
...
...
'At end of file...
Leads.Close()
Set Leads = Not
```

JavaScript section...

```js
$(function() {
var availableTags = ["<%=(Leads.Fields.Item("lead_desc").Value)%>"];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
  });
```

HTML section...

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags" name="NameCus">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you `console.log(availableTags);` ?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off reading the data into an array using [`GetRows()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675120(v=vs.85).aspx). You can then use this two dimensional array to populate the JavaScript code in-line...

```vbs
Dim rs, sql, res
sql = "SELECT lead_desc from dba.lead"
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
rs.Open sql, MM_PSCRM_STRING, 0, 1, 1
res = rs.GetRows()
rs.Close()
Set rs = Nothing
Dim c, arr
For c = 0 To UBound(res, 2)
    arr = arr & res(0, c) & ""","""
Next
arr = """" & Left(arr, Len(arr)-1) & """" 'Chop off the last comma
```

*(As reminded by Martha):* There is also the [`GetString` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676975(v=vs.85).aspx) of the RecordSet object:

```
Dim rs, sql, res
sql = "SELECT lead_desc from dba.lead"
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
rs.Open sql, MM_PSCRM_STRING, 0, 1, 1
arr = rs.GetString(,,,",")
rs.Close()
Set rs = Nothing
```

*(I am assuming that you're using SQL Server):* If you do this in SQL you can use the `STUFF` method of compiling the string into a list. I would recommend that you use a stored procedure for this, though.

```vbs
Dim rs, sql, res
sql = _
    "SELECT STUFF((" & _
        "SELECT " & _
            "',' + lead_desc " & _
        "FROM " & _
            "dba.lead " & _
        "ORDER BY " & _
            "dba.lead " & _
        "FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') " 
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
rs.Open sql, MM_PSCRM_STRING, 0, 1, 1
res = rs.GetRows()
rs.Close()
Set rs = Nothing
```

And your JavaScript...

```js
var availableTags = [<%= arr %>];
```

Comment: Why use `STUFF` instead of `rs.GetString(...)`?

Comment: dear Paul
I use the database access.
follow your instructions it was also only display the first record in a database table.
you see the demo link and share what code I write has failed.
please just help me.

Demo : http://ksdemo.somee.com/sample4.asp
thank you

Comment: @Martha: Yes - I did forget about `GetString`. Well pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Change your javascript code to following :

```
<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = ["<%
Do Until Leads.EOF
 Response.Write(Leads.Fields.Item("lead_desc").Value & ",")
 Leads.Movenext 
Loop
%>"];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
  });
});
</script>
```

It is because you forgot to execute statement in loop. So, only first element is loaded into the autocomplete. Hope this helps :)

Comment: hi Jadeja
So it has to fully select records. but when choosing a name any it's still just focus on the first record.
Can you help me to choose the correct focus is not?
thank you!

Comment: Sure can you prepare demo in jsfiddle with static data generated by .asp code?

Answer (score 0):

Thank everyone for the support.
I did it this way

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
<!--
    $(function() {
$( "#productname" ).autocomplete({
source: "list.asp",
        minLength: 2
    });
   });
// -->
</script>
```